# Call JS on site using WebView

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

There is a site where I want to run JS script like:

```
document.getElementById("statuses").rows[2].cells[1].firstChild.nodeValue
```

and get some result. I've added `WebView` and tried to implement that:

**MainActivity.OnCreate**

```
WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
wv.SetWebViewClient(new Client());
wv.LoadUrl("http://inout.test.com/");
```

Then **Cleint**

```
public class Client : WebViewClient {

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url) {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        var script = $"javascript: document.getElementById(\"statuses\").rows[2].cells[1].firstChild.nodeValue";
        //view.LoadUrl($"javascript: {script}");
        view.EvaluateJavascript(script , new JsResult());
    }
}
```

And **JsResult**

```
public class JsResult : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback {

    public string Result;
    public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object value) {
        Result = ((Java.Lang.String)value).ToString();
    }
}
```

But `Result` is always empty! What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to get value from JS? Please help.

Comment: `return 42;` is returning an integer/number. Have you had a look at the actual type of `value`?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter because I've tried return 'Hello' instead of 42. The actual type of `value` is `Java.Lang.Object `

Comment: Sorry with "the actual type" I meant the type of the object itself not of the variable. The type of the object is `Java.Lang.String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute

```
function() { alert('hello world'); return 42; } ()
```

in Chrome developer console, you end up with

[image]

You just have to use correct brackets:

```
(function() { alert('hello world'); return 42; }) ()
```

And then you see:

[image]

Comment: Excuse me sir. I upvote your answer but there are a mistake in the question (my bad). I've fixed id. Please see and help. Thanks and sorry again

Comment: have you executed it in chrome, first  to see if it returns what you expect? ^^

Comment: also I tried this: `(function(){return document.getElementById('statuses').rows[2].cells[1].firstChild.nodeValue;})()` but no result. Can I run JS on any websites or it should be special

Comment: just remove `javascript: `. This is working in my test. The `(function(){...})()` way is working too

Comment: No, no result. Could you please check it on this real website http://inout.osdn.nl/? Maybe there are some problem with it/ Thanks

Comment: I wanna get `Agratina Michael` in my Result

Comment: The problem is, that this is a dynamic website... The table is generated with javascript after the site has loaded. But it's loading it's data from http://inout.osdn.nl/index/ajax/format/json so you can load it with a simple webrequest via HTTPClient.